# Understanding weird boolean 2d-array indexing behavior in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this work:

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 20)
x_range = np.arange(10)
y_range = np.arange(20)

a_tmp = a[x_range<5,:]
b = a_tmp[:, np.in1d(y_range, [3,4,8])]
```

and this does not:

```
a = np.random.rand(10,20)
x_range = np.arange(10)
y_range = np.arange(20)    

b = a[x_range<5, np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8])]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Numpy reference documentation's [page on indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean) contains the answers, but requires a bit of careful reading.

The answer here is that indexing with booleans is equivalent to indexing with integer arrays obtained by first transforming the boolean arrays with `np.nonzero`. Therefore, with boolean arrays `m1`, `m2`

```
a[m1, m2] == a[m1.nonzero(), m2.nonzero()]
```

which (when it succeeds, i.e., `m1.nonzero().shape == m2.nonzero().shape`) is equivalent to:

```
[a[i, i] for i in range(a.shape[0]) if m1[i] and m2[i]]
```

I'm not sure why it was designed to work like this --- usually, this is *not* what you'd want.

To get the more intuitive result, you can instead do

```
a[np.ix_(m1, m2)]
```

which produces a result equivalent to

```
[[a[i,j] for j in range(a.shape[1]) if m2[j]] for i in range(a.shape[0]) if m1[i]]
```

Comment: It really does not make sense. I'll ask in the maillist why it is this way.

Comment: [scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing](http://scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing) p. 14 on Multidimenional Boolean Indexing says "look into numpy's masked array tools ... The obvious approach doesn't give the right answer." (That document is well-written, needs updating.)

Comment: @denis, circa 2013 that document does explain it rather well. However, if you google numpy logical indexing, the document that comes up is http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html and it isn't explained nearly as well.

Comment: it succeeds if `m1.nonzero()[0].shape == m2.nonzero()[0].shape`, at least in current version.

Comment: And it is not equivalent to `[a[i,i] ...]` but to

`[a[i,j] for i,j in zip(m1.nonzero()[0], m2.nonzero()[0])]`

Comment: Oh, I see what you had in mind: with `a[m1,m2]` you get the diagonal of the intended result: `a[m1,m2] == diag(a[m1,:][:,m2])`.  (Supposing that `m1.sum() == m2.sum()`, of course.)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to `np.ix_` is to convert the boolean arrays to integer arrays (using `np.nonzero()`), and then use `np.newaxis` to create arrays of the right shape to take advantage of broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.random.rand(10,20)
x_range=np.arange(10)
y_range=np.arange(20)

a_tmp=a[x_range<5,:]
b_correct=a_tmp[:,np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8])]

m1=(x_range<5).nonzero()[0]
m2=np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8]).nonzero()
b=a[m1[:,np.newaxis], m2]
assert np.allclose(b,b_correct)

b2=a[np.ix_(x_range<5,np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8]))]
assert np.allclose(b2,b_correct)
```

`np.ix_` tends to be slower than double indexing. 
The long-form solution appears to be a bit faster:

**long-form**:

```
In [83]: %timeit a[(x_range<5).nonzero()[0][:,np.newaxis], (np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8])).nonzero()[0]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 131 us per loop
```

**double indexing**:

```
In [85]: %timeit a[x_range<5,:][:,np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8])]
10000 loops, best of 3: 144 us per loop
```

**using np.ix_**:

```
In [84]: %timeit a[np.ix_(x_range<5,np.in1d(y_range,[3,4,8]))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 160 us per loop
```

Note: It would be a good idea to test these timings on your machine since the rankings might change depending on your version of Python, numpy, or hardware.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that still struggles to understand what is going on

`Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney` has a good explanations:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781449323592/ch04.html
chapter: "Fancy Indexing"

In short.

1. A boolean indexes are converted to arrays of indexes using np.nonzero as @pv. explained.
2. Then we have two "fancy" indexes, which means selecting 1d array of elements for corresponding tuple of indexes.

```
>>> A=np.arange(0,9).reshape(3,-1)*10
>>> A
array([[ 0, 10, 20],
       [30, 40, 50],
       [60, 70, 80]])

>>> A[[1,2],[0,1]]
array([30, 70])
```

As you can see it selected the values at indexes 1,0 and 2,1

```
>>> [A[1,0], A[2,1]] 
[30, 70]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is to select the per-axis indices you want separately, i.e.:

```py
A[rows, :][:, cols]
```

Concrete example:

```py
>>> A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> A
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

# Slicing works as expected.
>>> A[1:, :2]
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 7]])

# Indices that represent slice.
>>> cols = [0, 1]
>>> rows = [1, 2]
# Per OP, counterintuitively different.
>>> A[rows, cols]
array([3, 7])

# Workaround: Select axes separately.
>>> A[rows, :][:, cols]
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 7]])
```

(silly code to produce above text: [link](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/ab05f38/python/numpy/logical_indexing_2d_counterintuitive.py))