# Indexing columns (or rows) in a numpy matrix with a Boolean list

Tags: numpy, indexing

Given a numpy matrix `A` of shape `(m,n)` and a list `ind` of Boolean values with length `n`, I want to extract the columns of `A` where the corresponding element of the Boolean list is true.

My first naive try

```
Asub = A[:,cols]
```

gives quite weird results, not necessary to cite here...

Following pv.'s answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820809/understanding-weird-boolean-2d-array-indexing-behavior-in-numpy), I tried with `numpy.ix_` as follows:

```
>>> A = numpy.diag([1,2,3])
>>> ind = [True, True, False]
>>> A[:,numpy.ix_(ind)]
array([[[1, 0]],

       [[0, 2]],

       [[0, 0]]])
>>> A[:,numpy.ix_(ind)].shape
(3, 1, 2)
```

Now the result is of inappropriate shape: I want to have a `(3,2)` resulting array. I guess I could collapse the result down to two dimensions, but there surely must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [docs discuss](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), boolean indexing like you want "occurs when obj is an array object of Boolean type (such as may be returned from comparison operators)."

IOW, `ind` needs to be an `ndarray` of type `bool`:

```
In [15]: A = numpy.diag([1,2,3])

In [16]: ind = [True, True, False]

In [17]: A[:,ind]
Out[17]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

which occurs because it's interpreting the bools as integers, and giving you columns `[1, 1, 0]`.

OTOH:

```
In [18]: A[:,numpy.array(ind)]
Out[18]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `ind` to an array:

```
>>> A[:, np.array(ind)]
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 0]])
```